# ASP.NET 3.5 bind to XML string

Tags: asp.net, xml, string, binding

With ASP.NET 3.5 I can easily bind to an XML file by using an `XmlDataSource`.

How can I bind to an XML *string* instead of a *file*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [XmlDataSource.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.data.aspx) property.

```
XmlDataSource dataSource    = new XmlDataSource();
dataSource.Data             = "<root><element>Item #1</element><element>Item #2</element></root>";
dataSource.XPath            = "root/element";
dataSource.DataBind();
```

Alternately, you could specify the data declaratively:

```
<asp:xmldatasource 
  id="XmlDataSource1" 
  runat="server" 
>
  <data>
    <Books>
      <LanguageBooks>
        <Book Title="Pure JavaScript" Author="Wyke, Gilliam, and Ting"/>
        <Book Title="Effective C++ Second Edition" Author="Scott Meyers"/>
        <Book Title="Assembly Language Step-By-Step" Author="Jeff Duntemann"/>
        <Book Title="Oracle PL/SQL" Author="Steven Feuerstein"/>
      </LanguageBooks>

      <SecurityBooks>
        <Book Title="Counter Hack" Author="Ed Skoudis"/>
      </SecurityBooks>

    </Books>
  </data>
</asp:xmldatasource>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the XmlDataSource docs [here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.aspx)

> *XML data can also be stored directly by the data source control in string form using the Data property*.