# How to bind xml elements to the GridView using the xmlDataSourse?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview, xpath

I have a service returning xmlData in a string format:

```
    <CourseSearchDataSet xmlns="http:/www.tempuri.org/CourseSearchDataSet.xsd">
     <Course>
       <CourseId>9e980791</CourseId>
       <CourseName>Library and Information Solutions</CourseName>
       <CourseDesc>Overview of Library</CourseDesc>
     </Course>
     <Course>
       <CourseId>f3e59e56</CourseId>
       <CourseName>Power Link Intro</CourseName>
       <CourseDesc>This course</CourseDesc>
     </Course>
</CourseSearchDataSet>
```

At runtime I am trying to bind this data to GridView using the xmlDataSource.

I have defined a grid and dataSource at the design time:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdCourses" XPath="Course/">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                          <%# XPath("CourseId") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    <asp:XmlDataSource runat="server" ID="xmlDataSource"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

At design time I am assigning the data to the xmlDataSource and assigning xmlDataSource to grid:

```
 xmlDataSource.EnableCaching = false;
        xmlDataSource.DataFile =  courseList;
        grdCourses.DataSourceID = "xmlDataSource";
```

("courseList" is a string holding service result).

The grid has been binded to the xmldDataSource but its not displaying the CourseId (the fields defined in templateField, no error, just blank columns.

I am referring to this tutorial: http://goo.gl/mUHkYm
I don't want to use DATASET since its messy and requires many events to be handled manually.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just your namespace which was causing problem, try below code .

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(@"D:\xxxx\xxx\xx\xxx\test.xml");
            XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
            XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
            manager.AddNamespace("bk", "http:/www.tempuri.org/CourseSearchDataSet.xsd");
        }
```

aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="/test.xml">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdCourses" AutoGenerateColumns="false" XPath="bk:courseSearchDataSet/bk:Course" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                          <%# XPath("CourseId") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>       
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I don't have a datafile, I am getting xml data from the webservice and assigning it to xmlDataSource and then binding xmlDataSource to gridview.

Answer (score 0):

If you have XML string data instead of XML file, you should bind the XML string to `XmlDataSource` by setting `Data` property instead of `DataFile` :

```
xmlDataSource.EnableCaching = false;
xmlDataSource.Data =  courseList;
grdCourses.DataSourceID = "xmlDataSource";
dataSource.XPath = "....";
dataSource.DataBind();
```

Related question : [ASP.NET 3.5 bind to XML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322190/asp-net-3-5-bind-to-xml-string)

Comment: No luck i believe the format of this xml is not supported by the xmlDataSource.